# How i can install psutil on a alpine chroot on arch linux?

Tags: python-3.x, linux, gcc, alpine-linux, psutil

Well, i need an alpine chroot for run my Mongo DB Server, but i can't because when i run the /usr/bin/python3 -m pip install -r etc/pip/compile-requirements.txt, it return's to me this error:

```
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fomit-frame-pointer -g -fno-semantic-interposition -fomit-frame-pointer -g -fno-semantic-interposition -fomit-frame-pointer -g -fno-semantic-interposition -DTHREAD_STACK_SIZE=0x100000 -fPIC -DPSUTIL_POSIX=1 -DPSUTIL_SIZEOF_PID_T=4 -DPSUTIL_VERSION=580 -DPSUTIL_LINUX=1 -DPSUTIL_ETHTOOL_MISSING_TYPES=1 -I/usr/include/python3.9 -c psutil/_psutil_common.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.9/psutil/_psutil_common.o
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fomit-frame-pointer -g -fno-semantic-interposition -fomit-frame-pointer -g -fno-semantic-interposition -fomit-frame-pointer -g -fno-semantic-interposition -DTHREAD_STACK_SIZE=0x100000 -fPIC -DPSUTIL_POSIX=1 -DPSUTIL_SIZEOF_PID_T=4 -DPSUTIL_VERSION=580 -DPSUTIL_LINUX=1 -DPSUTIL_ETHTOOL_MISSING_TYPES=1 -I/usr/include/python3.9 -c psutil/_psutil_linux.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.9/psutil/_psutil_linux.o
    psutil/_psutil_linux.c:19:10: fatal error: linux/version.h: No such file or directory
       19 | #include <linux/version.h>
          |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    compilation terminated.
    error: command '/usr/bin/gcc' failed with exit code 1
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /usr/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-o_fhhi2e/psutil_0a9d27309a03482b80a67c750b3ed64d/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-o_fhhi2e/psutil_0a9d27309a03482b80a67c750b3ed64d/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-h383bgkd/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /usr/include/python3.9/psutil Check the logs for full command output.
```

I searched it on Google, and i dont founded anything.

Comment: Can this help ? https://askubuntu.com/questions/390995/help-locating-linux-version-h

Comment: Please note that Stack Overflow is for programming questions and not questions about using or setting up Linux. Please review [What topics can I ask here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for more details. Question may be appropriate for [Super User](http://superuser.com) or [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com) but do check their help before posting.

Comment: `apk add py3-psutil`?

Answer (score 1):

Try installing linux headers :

RUN apk add linux-headers